# mongoose push doesnt work inside socket.io call

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, mongoose

For some reason, the push to mongodb works with this setup

```
// Fixed params
story.title = 'Socketi';
story.lines.push ({ author: 'Khuram', text:'socket data'});


//Capture data from socket into schema
 io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });

socket.on('slog', function (data) {

console.log(data);

    });
});
```

But placing the mongoose push statement within the socket.io call doesnt work

Like so:

```
// Fixed params
story.title = 'Socketi';



  //Capture data from socket into schema
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });

socket.on('slog', function (data) {

story.lines.push ({ author: 'Khuram', text:data.my});

    });
});
```

Just for reference purposes: 'slog' refers to the event that i want mongoose to update on.
Im receiving data from the client and i want to push the socket event data to mongodb each time this event is emitted (which is why i want to place it within the socket.io call)

Comment: How are you checking if `story.lines.push` worked? Lot's of code missing here.

Comment: I just pasted a section of the code to keep it concise. I do have all the code for the schema above it. I have tested the story.push outside of the socket.io call and the data gets stored successfully into MongoDB - Does that answer your question?

Comment: You're probably having trouble with concurrency, but it's impossible to tell without seeing the complete code. Try running your code and then checking the database via the mongo console. Are you calling `.save()` on `story`?

Comment: Here is the link to the complete code on GitHub: https://github.com/eemouk/Storify/blob/master/story.js

Comment: Try this: https://gist.github.com/ca3f8927b6a6cbdd3039

Comment: This worked. Thank you. Since both yours and @idefine answer was correct i didnt know who to mark as the correct answer but as he posted it as an answer ive marked his correct and upvoted your comment. Hope thats ok? If there is something i else i can do for you where you would feel better rewarded then please let me know? Thank you also for watching my repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your save function executing? I'd recommend putting all your logic for what you want to have happen when you receive a slog message in it's callback and then calling save on instance of story in your callback as well.

Comment: Thats pretty much what i have been trying to do, but i dont think im implementing correctly. Here is the complete code on GitHub:

https://github.com/eemouk/Storify/blob/master/story.js

Comment: there is no callback for push. it is a built in operation for arrays. Just do the save after you do the push, not in a callback (it doesn't exist).

Comment: I've tried that previously. The problem is, the code iterates right through to save without waiting for data to be received from the Socket on event. The result of this is that it doesnt capture any data from the client. How do i get around that problem?

Comment: you are terminating the database connection at the end of your file, you don't want to do that there. Also I placed your save function properly below the push, as I mentioned above. Here you go: https://gist.github.com/1774024

Comment: OK - Thanks. Let me try this and report back to you.

Comment: FYI, I updated the gist to remove the port number I was using (1337) to connect to my mongodb.